# Vue.js how to implement custom filter before API variable is defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a basic custom filter for my vue.js app which I intend to use extensively for y API variables. This is the filter in my *app.js* file:

```
filters: {
   myFilter: function(val) {
   return val.toFixed(0)
  }
},
```

In my *index.html* I simply call it like this

```
<p> {{ foo.bar.num | myFilter }} </p>
```

This returns an error. `Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined`. The problem is `foo.bar.num` is not defined until the API is loaded. The API has so many variables I want to use for my custom filter that it would be impractical to pre-define them all in the data option.

What would be the best approach in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a default value:

```
return typeof val == 'undefined' ? 0 : val.toFixed(0)
```

The warning is not from the filter but is from `<p> {{ foo.bar.num }} </p>`.  The way to solve that would be to define:

```
data() {
  return {
    foo:{bar:{num:0}}}
  }
}
```

in your component.  This can be overkill, and sometimes you don't know the structure of the object already.  Anyway, the warning only shows when `Vue.config.debug` is `true`, so it should go away in production.

Comment: The solution nows gives me a warning, `[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "foo.bar.num".` but at least it's not breaking the app. I'll accept your answer, and will upvote any solution that spares me of the console warning.

Answer (score 0):

Did'nt test this but did you tried one of the lifecycle hooks?

Keep

```
<p> {{ foo.bar.num }} </p>
```

And do

```
var Foo = new Vue({
    // el and data and stuff
    ready: function () {
       this.$options.filters.myFilter(this.foo.bar.num);
    }
});
```

Another approach might be the computed option: http://vuejs.org/api/#computed

Comment: Thanks. While this is viable, it would also be impractical to apply it to a large amount of variables.